# How do I exclude ant testing?

Tags: java, ant, build, travis-ci

I am trying to build a relatively simple java project on TravisCI but it keeps failing because the default Java build configurations include Ant testing.

My .travis.yml is quite minimal, as you can see:

```
language: java
```

However, when TravisCI runs it, I get an ant-related error, as seen in the end of my build log:

```
[0K$ ant test
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
travis_time:end:173ed83c:start=1439310746598741958,finish=1439310746782527658,duration=183785700
[0K
[31;1mThe command "ant test" exited with 1.[0m

Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

I've searched for how to exclude but just adding an exclude like this doesn't seem to work.

```
language: java
    exclude: 
           -ant
```

Does anybody know how to exclude ant-related tests?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you should use `script` directive:

```
  matrix:
  - JOB="./gradlew build"

script: "$JOB"
```

or

```
before_install:
  - cd java
```

The reason for that is ant pre installed on travis